# Error al inyectar Sweetalert en controlador AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, sweetalert, sweetalert2, angularjs-injector

Estoy teniendo problemas para injectar sweetalert en mi aplicacion angular:

**Dependencias**

- angular: 1.6.4
- angular-sweetalert: latests

El proceso que utilice fue el siguiente

1. Instale sweetalert via bower -> bower install angular-sweetalert.
2. Inserte los archivo css y js en el archivo index.

   - `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js' %}"></script>`
   - `<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="{% static 'bower_components/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css' %}">`
3. Injectar la dependencia en mi controlador.
   `main.controller.js`

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('project.layout.controllers')
        .controller('MainController', MainController)

    MainController.$inject = ['$window', '$document', '$uibModal', '$http', '$location', '$rootScope', '$scope', 'Authentication', 'Constants', 'Enums', 'UserService', 'Snackbar', 'ErrorHandler', 'AddressService', 'AdminService', 'Urls', 'RealtimeService', 'DoctorService', 'PatientService', '$timeout', 'Utils', <b>'SweetAlert'</b>];

    function MainController($window, $document, $uibModal, $http, $location, $rootScope, $scope, Authentication, Constants, Enums, UserService, Snackbar, ErrorHandler, AddressService, AdminService, Urls, RealtimeService, DoctorService, PatientService, $timeout, <b>SweetAlert</b>) {

    ...
}
```

Haciendo esto obtengo el siguiente error:

```
angular.js:14525 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: SweetAlertProvider <- SweetAlert <- MainController
```

Si alguien conoce la causa de este error, de antemano gracias.

Comment: ¿puedes verificar y asegurar que tus archivos js se están cargando?

Comment: Sí, los archivos js y css se estan cargando correctamente. El problema radica cuando  lo injecto en MainController

Answer (score 0):

Faltó agregar el JS para el *wrapper* de sweet alert (para AngularJS), allí sólo se está agregando SweetAlert, faltaría cargar angular-sweetalert.

Bastaría agregar el script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bower_components/angular-sweetalert/SweetAlert.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Y en el módulo del controlador registrar el módulo del *wrapper* (Esto en el archivo donde tengas la declaración del módulo y el registro para los módulos que se inyecten).

```js
angular.module('project.layout.controllers', [
    // Los otros módulos registrados
    ...
    'oitozero.ngSweetAlert'
])
```